# How to Write UDAF function for Hive using Java

Tags: java, hive, user-defined-functions, user-agent

I have a Hive table "log_data" which has columns:

**"User_Agent"**(Example User_Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)") and column **city**.

I should write UDAF function `parsed_user_agent` which is used like below -

```
SELECT city, parsed_user_agent(User_Agent) group by city
```

In the result I should get info from User_Agent (operation system, browser and device) for each city.

Specifically I should use class which extended by AbstractGenericUDAFResolver.class.

- **PROBLEM**. I don't know how to implement this logic, but I know how to parse user agent and I don't know how to deal with input(String User_Agent) and outputs(Structure of OS, browser and device).

Comment: Could you paste your code here?

Comment: Really, I don't have implementation of code, because I don't know how to works with input(user agent) and output(OS, browser, device).
I just know how to parse User Agent.

But I have little example of implementation , but it is very easy. It has just one output parameter
https://blog.dataiku.com/2013/05/01/a-complete-guide-to-writing-hive-udf

Comment: Within two days I am also going to practice on creating jar for **UDAF** on using hive functions.

Comment: In my opinion I should create three maps. Map<String, Integer>
One map for browsers
Second for OS
Third for device.
Key - name of (OS , device, browser)
Value - count of using in city.
And in the end I get the key by biggest value

Comment: @ArifMustafa, it is easy, But I can't find required info for implementation

Comment: @Павел Орлов but I am completely sure and will definite create a jar then and there when I will practice on the same.... :D

Answer (score 0):

When I'm right and user_agent has always the same structure, why don't you use regexp_extract?

e.g.

```
select regexp_extract('Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)', '(\\S*).*', 1)
```

Comment: For parsing, I will use API 
https://github.com/HaraldWalker/user-agent-utils

But problem is not in parsing, I need create UDAF jar. which give me most popular data (OS, device, browser) per city

Comment: @ПавелОрлов You should not put the functionality to get the most popular (...) per city in a UDF, just the parsing. You can get the most popular thing afterwards with just SQL (group by, count, rank etc)

Comment: He is right. You have to do something like this:

select *
 FROM (
select city, device, browser, numbers,
   row_number() over (partition by city order by numbers desc) rowNo
from (SELECT city, device, browser, count(*) numbers
        FROM your_table
      GROUP BY city, device,browser ) x
   ) xx
where rowNo = 1